# How set transaction isolation level to ReadUncommitted in SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, isolation-level, read-uncommitted

According to the answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283765/readuncommitted-broken-in-sqllite-against-nhibernate) it states:

> Did you know that ReadUncommitted will revert to Serialized isolation unless you've enabled the shared cache and both connections are from the same thread?

Working in C#, I then went ahead and defined a DLL import as follows:

```
[DllImport("System.Data.SQLite.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int sqlite3_enable_shared_cache(int enable);
```

I called this function to enable the cache and got a successful result status of 0 when called. Nonetheless, I still get the exception "isolationlevel", when executing the below lines and attempting to set the isolation level to ReadUncommitted.

```
string connectionString = @"data source=d:\db\test.db3;datetimeformat=Ticks";
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
IDbTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
```

This question is related to another question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367118/how-perform-sqlite-query-with-a-data-reader-without-locking-database).

How can I pull off a query with an isolation level of ReadUncommitted in SQLite?

Comment: Can you please show a little more of your source code following BeginTransaction? Is there any reason you are assigning conn.BeginTransaction to an Interface rather than Concrete type?

Comment: In actuality I am using the provider factory, but for the sake of this posting, I simplified the code to isolate the exception. The exception occurs right on the call to conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommited). While I can post more code, I am not clear why code after this is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish uncommitted reads see the following question and answer:

[How perform SQLite query with a data reader without locking database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367118/how-perform-sqlite-query-with-a-data-reader-without-locking-database)